# Pass array to PowerShell script executed with -File argument

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameters

I have simple script which takes array argument:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$keys
)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $keys.Length; ++$i) {
    Write-Host "$i. $($keys[$i])"
}
```

I need to execute it via powershell with -File argument (in order to address a TeamCity bug) like so:

```
powershell.exe -File Untitled2.ps1 -keys a
```

How can I pass parameter as array to my script? As long as I pass single key it works well, but it don't want to take more than one element.

I tried following among others:

```
powershell.exe -File Untitled2.ps1 -keys a,b
powershell.exe -File Untitled2.ps1 -keys:a,b
powershell.exe -File Untitled2.ps1 -keys $keys # where $keys is an array
```

Whatever I'd tried either I have "A positional parameter cannot be found" error, or all keys are joined in first array element.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `"a","b"` or `@("a","b")`? or `start-process` with `-argumentlist`?

Comment: Yes, and few others with same result

Comment: I need to use -file, because it is executed from teamcity, and it has bug which causes infinite loop in some cases when -Command is used.

Comment: This bypasses the requirment but could you pass the array as a string then cast it in the script instead with a Split for example?

Comment: Casting won't work, but it is quite obvious that I can pass param as csv for example an process it, but since ps supports array params, it should work for -File too. If it is not supported then I will be forced to do it differently, but for now nobody stated that this isn't supported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is another try. Note the `ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true` in the parameters declaration:

```
param([parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
    [string[]]$keys)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $keys.Length; ++$i) {
    Write-Host "$i. $($keys[$i])"
}
```

Then I called the script via powershell.exe using the -file argument:

```
powershell.exe -File d:\scripts\array.ps1 "1" "a" "c"
```

This works to pass all those parameters as an array, the output is:

```
0. 1
1. a
2. c
```

In case you need to pass additional parameters you can name them in the usual way, such as:

```
param([parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
    [string[]]$keys,
    [string] $dummy)
```

And you can pass the additional parameters such as this:

```
powershell.exe -File d:\scripts\array.ps1 "1" "a" "c" -dummy "Z"
```

The `$dummy` parameter will in this case receive the value `Z` while the values of `"1" "a" "c"` will still be assigned to `$keys` as an array.

So if change the script to display the value of `$dummy` along with the rest I get:

```
0. 1
1. a
2. c
Dummy param is z
```

Comment: I know that this works, but it don't answer my question.

Comment: Modified answer to use -File.

Comment: As long as there is one array parameter in script it does the job.